# How to get all modified wiki pages after specifc date inside a PNP script

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have the following powershell which I use to loop through a wiki page library inside my On-Premise site, and filter out all the wiki pages which have been modified after a certain date:

```
$startdate = Get-Date -Day 05 -Month 03 -Year 2018 -Hour 16 -Minute 00 
$startDateIsoFormat = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($startdate)
$emailbody =""
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://****/kb/info"
$userfriendlyURL  = "http://www.*****.intra/kb/info"
$list = $web.GetList(($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd("/") + "/Pages"))  
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$camlQuery = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$startDateIsoFormat</Value></Geq></Where>";
$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)

foreach ($item in $listItems)
{   
    $emailbody = $emailbody + '<br/> <a href ="'    + $userfriendlyURL  + '/Pages/' + $item["LinkFilename"].toString() + '">'   + $item["Title"].toString() + '</a>' 
    Write-Host "found" 
}
```

Now, I want the same powershell script to run against a SharePoint Online site using PNP script, but I am not sure which commands I need to change and if I can run CAML queries against SP online libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Connect-PnPOnline` to connect to your site and then use the `Get-PnPListItem` command with `Query` parameter to get the filtered list items as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test" -UseWebLogin

$filterDate = Get-Date -Day 05 -Month 03 -Year 2018 -Hour 16 -Minute 00
$formattedDate = $filterDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")

$caml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$formattedDate</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"

$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "Pages" -Query $caml

foreach ($i in $items) {
    #do some stuff here 
}
```

You need to use the PnP SharePoint online PowerShell.

You can download it from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)